# fb like button code not working

Tags: facebook, html, xcode4, facebook-likebox

I have tried all of the options for inserting code to get a facebook like button on a clients website and it doesnt show up, can anyone help me with a simple code that will make the button work, the link to like is nnacanada

Answer (score 2):

First you have to create a app to get an app ID

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Second you have to generate the code for your like button here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ OR use the following code:

You need to put your html tag like that:

```
<html lang="pt" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

And between `<body>` and `</body>` you need to put the following code

```
<fb:like href="http://www.your.page.url" layout="standard" show-faces="true" send="true" width="450" action="like" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>



<!-- Facebook -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'your-facebook-app-id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

don't forget to replace "http://www.your.page.url" and "your-facebook-app-id" with correct values.

Comment: ok i just tried pasting this in a totally new blank page and still nothing what am i doing wrong

Comment: see again my main response, more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook provides this generator for making like's. 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

If it wont show up and is generated from there, its usually your fault. Check if you have Ghostery or similar plugins running. Also check if you use the FBML without including the needed Javascript.

Else just take the iFrame code Facebook provides.

Comment: i have tried every option of the facebook plugin provided and the iframe code and they dont work

Comment: Did you tried a different Browser? a different machine? Maybe you are trying this at work but facebooks plugin domain is blocked. Else there is no valid reason the iFrame would not work. Also are you sure there are no plugins blocking this? (Ghostery, Noscript, adblock, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. On https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ the popup with the code wasn't showing up.

On Chrome "Empty cache and hard reload" fixed it for me.
On FireFox clearing the history did the job.